Find max value of $P = \frac{a}{2a + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2} + \frac{b}{2b+c^2+a^2} + \frac{c}{2c + a ^ 2 + b ^ 2}$
For $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $a+b+c=3$.
Find max value of
$P = \frac{a}{2a + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2} + \frac{b}{2b + c ^ 2 + a ^ 2} + \frac{c}{2c + a ^ 2 + b ^ 2}$
Have: $(2a+b^2+c^2)(\frac{1}{a}+a+1+1)\ge(1+a+b+c)^2=16$ 
$\Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{2a+b^2+c^2}\le\frac{(a+1)^2}{16}$ 
$\Rightarrow P\le\frac{(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2+(c+1)^2}{16}$
I can't evaluate to a constant. Can anyone provide some hints for me?

Possible hint: We have $$2P = \dfrac{2a}{2a + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2} + \dfrac{2b}{2b+c^2+a^2} + \dfrac{2c}{2c + a ^ 2 + b ^ 2}$$ so we also have $$3-2P = \dfrac{b ^ 2 + c ^ 2}{2a + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2} + \dfrac{c^2+a^2}{2b+c^2+a^2} + \dfrac{a ^ 2 + b ^ 2}{2c + a ^ 2 + b ^ 2}.$$ Can we find the minimum value of $3-2P$ ? If so, we can deduce the maximum value of $P$ too.

Hint:
The maximum is at $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$ with value $P(1,1,1)=\frac{3}{4}$. If you can show that for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ with $a+b+c=3$:
$$ 2a+b^2+c^2\geq 4,$$
you are done.
Proof of this inequality:

Cauchy-Schwarz-Inequality yields for all $b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+:$ $$(b+c)^2\leq 2(b^2+c^2).$$
Using this fact:
$$\begin{align*}0&\leq (b+c-2)^2=(b+c)^2-4(b+c)+4\\&\leq2(b^2+c^2)-4(b+c)+4\end{align*}$$
Dividing by $2$ and substituting $b+c=3-a$:
$$\begin{align*}0&\leq (b^2+c^2)-2(3-a)+2\\&=b^2+c^2-6+2a+2\end{align*}\\$$
and thus:
$$4\leq 2a+b^2+c^2.$$


Very good answer. It might be simpler to just note that $2a+b^2+c^2 = (b-1)^2+(c-1)^2+4$.

Definitely simpler. Thanks for the comment :)
